# How to create randomely driven cars on SUMO

Tags: python, sumo

Ok, what i want is to create cars which **havn't predefined flows or trips**, because i want to make some **cars circulating randomely on a closed network**.

So i have a closed network and the only way i found to make something kinda similar to what i want is to generate a lot of differents trips with the script "randomTrips.py" in the SUMO/tools ...

But in fact this isn't a chaotic simulation because it's reproducible and that's not what i want !
I really want that each time an agent comes across an intersection he makes a random choice of where he'll go.

So if someone got an idea I apreciate

Answer (score 0):

Huu nobody got an idea ?

This environement will be used for deep Q learning application and i realy need my agents to randomize their choices

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the agents to start at the same time and/or place in every run you can just rerun randomTrips.py before every run. It will output different trips each time. You can also include a number of random intermediate waypoints using the "-i" option. If this is still not enough you could have a look at [rerouters](https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Rerouter) and place one of those on every possible edge.